# How can I pass values to another page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

For example...
I have several

```
<input type="text"/>
```

for users to input data on the current page ( let's say height, weight and body fat)

How can I pass these data to another page I made so I can use these data in that page to do calculations or analysis using JavaScript..? without saving these data in a server.

Comment: what about storing them in DB/session/cookies  ??

Comment: thats what cokies are for..  but since the European Union doesn't really like them, you need a disclaimer..

Comment: You could use html5 webstorage if you are not using any server side language.

Comment: or load the pages in an iframe, and keep the data in the master frames memory

Comment: @Henrik, this wouldn't really be a problem with the EU as these wouldn't be tracking cookies. OP: you could pass them on as GET parameters? Or as hashes in the URL? But why do you want to got to another page anyway.. why not put everything in one page?

Comment: use local storage in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Browser storage** to do this task

Browser storage is easy to create, access, manipulate and delete using javascript.

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)